# How can i use Google API in VUE?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I'm linking Google's login API to a web project.

I'm trying one by one while looking at the official document.
The script is declared in `index.html`

I do not recognize the function(?) declared in Google 
(like `gapi`... and initialized method)

**How do I fix this?**

```
    <template>
     <div class="g-signin2" :data-onsuccess="onSignIn">Login</div>
    </template>

<script>
     methods: {
          onSignIn: function (googleUser) {
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
            console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
            console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
            // auth2 is initialized with gapi.auth2.init() and a user is signed in.

            if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
              var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
              console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
              console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
              console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
              console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
              console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
              console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
            }
          },

</script>
```

thank you!

Comment: Is it your full code or just part of it? Because your component is not exported, you should start it inside the script tag with 'export default {}'... Anyway, here is an NPM-package for google auth, you should try it: https://github.com/guruahn/vue-google-oauth2#readme

Comment: it's part of code
anyway thank you

Comment: Another question: what is the error message? Does it say that gapi is undefined?

Comment: yes 
//Error in data(): "ReferenceError: gapi is not defined"
//ReferenceError: gapi is not defined at VueComponent.data
//Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: gapi is not defined" ... etc
i think not recognize it vue

Comment: I found another npm package: https://github.com/cedpoilly/vue-gapi . If it is undefined, you should check your script link in index.html. Is it enqueued before Vue?